# Timestamp to LocalDateTime conversion

Tags: flutter

I am reading a date from Firestore which is of type Timestamp and I want it converted as a LocalDateTime type.

To do so, I used the following procedure:

- Convert the Timestamp to a DateTime
- Use the .dateTime method of LocalDateTime to convert it to a LocalDateTime
- Manually adjust it to my local time

`LocalDateTime.dateTime(entity.start.toDate()).addHours(2),`

Although `entity.start.toDate()` has my local time the `.dateTime` does some adjustments and I get some other time.

Also, this method is prone to errors sinve I am adjusting something manually.

Another way to do so would be the following but I find it too long:

```
DateTime hStartDate = entity.start.toDate();
LocalDateTime(hStartDate.year,hStartDate.month,hStartDate.day,hStartDate.hour,hStartDate.minute,0)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For LocalDateTime you are using time_machine lib?

Comment: @Nuts yes correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues I wasnt able to find a way to convert Timestamp String to Timestamp object again. 
So i used this way out.

***When you save data to firestore:***

Use -

```
DateTime.now().toString()
```

Example :

```
 await Firestore.instance
        .collection("users/$docId/tokens")
        .document(fcm.deviceToken)
        .setData({
      "token": fcm.deviceToken,
      "timestamp": DateTime.now().toString()
    });
```

***When u get data from firestore and get the timestamp string:***

Use this to get **DateTime** object -

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(timestamp)
```

Use this to get **TimeOfDay** object -

```
TimeOfDay timeOfDay = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(dateTime);
timeOfDay.format(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **toLocal ( )** method.

> **something like this.**

```
_getDate(//timestamp, "yyyy.dd.MM, HH:mm");

String _getDate(int timestamp, String dateFormat) {
  DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
    timestamp * 1000,
  ).toLocal();
  String formattedDateTime = DateFormat(dateFormat).format(date);
  return formattedDateTime;
}
```